# JavaScript using script in React.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a script Written in JavaScript, it draws some circles and lines that have some loops in it as an SVG. I want to use it in React.js but it is producing some errors that I don't know how to fix.

```
var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var radius = 400;
text_r = 430;
var point_size = 10;
var center_x = 500;
var center_y = 500;

function GraphCirclePoint(step, gappoint, nodlist) {
    var indexgappoint = 0;
    var indexnodelist = 0;
    for (var point = 0; point < 360; point += step) {
        if (gappoint[indexgappoint][0] != point) {

            if (nodlist[indexnodelist][0] == point) {
                drawPoint(point, 1, nodlist[indexnodelist][1], nodlist[indexnodelist][2]);
                indexnodelist++;
                if (indexnodelist >= nodlist.length)
                    indexnodelist--;
            } else {

                drawPoint(point, 1, "reserved");
            }
        } else if (indexgappoint < gappoint.length) {

            point = gappoint[indexgappoint][1];
            indexgappoint++;
            if (indexgappoint >= gappoint.length)
                indexgappoint--;
        }
    }
}

function GraphCircleLine(listline) {
    for (var i = 0; i < listline.length; i++) {
        var child = listline[i][6];
        if (child.length > 0) {
            for (var j = 0; j < child.length; j++) {
                var x = child[j];
                drawline(listline[i][2], listline[x][2], listline[i][3], listline[i][4]);
                tagHover('.' + listline[i][2], '.' + listline[i][4], listline[i][3]);
            }
        }
    }
}

function drawPoint(angle, distance, label, ID) {
    var x = center_x + radius * Math.cos(-angle * Math.PI / 180) * distance;
    var y = center_y + radius * Math.sin(-angle * Math.PI / 180) * distance;

    var xx = center_x + text_r * Math.cos(-angle * Math.PI / 180) * distance;
    var yy = center_y + text_r * Math.sin(-angle * Math.PI / 180) * distance;

    var circle = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'circle');
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', x);
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', y);
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', 5);
    circle.setAttribute("id", ID);
    circle.setAttribute("fill", "white");

    var line = document.createElementNS(svgns, "path");
    line.setAttribute("d", "M" + x + " " + y + "L" + "500 500");
    line.setAttribute("stroke", "white");
    line.setAttribute("stroke-width", 0.5);

    var text = document.createElementNS(svgns, "text");
    text.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', xx);
    text.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', yy);

    $(text).attr({
        "font-size": 20,
        "class": label,
        "fill": "white",
        "text-anchor": "start"
    });
    text.innerHTML = label;


    text.setAttribute("transform", " rotate(" + (Math.abs(angle) * -1) + "," + xx + "," + yy + ")");
    if (angle >= 125 && angle <= 235) {
        //text.setAttribute("text-anchor", "end");
    }

    document.getElementById("text").appendChild(text);
    document.getElementById("ttt").appendChild(circle);
    document.getElementById("ttt").appendChild(line);
}

function drawline(point1, point2, color, clsn) {
    var line = document.createElementNS(svgns, "path")
    var pointx1 = document.getElementById(point1).getAttribute("cx");
    var pointy1 = document.getElementById(point1).getAttribute("cy");
    var pointx2 = document.getElementById(point2).getAttribute("cx");
    var pointy2 = document.getElementById(point2).getAttribute("cy");
    document.getElementById(point1).setAttribute("fill", "crimson")
    document.getElementById(point2).setAttribute("fill", "crimson");
    document.getElementById(point1).setAttribute("class", "cnct")
    document.getElementById(point2).setAttribute("class", "cnct");

    var Wline2 = document.createElementNS(svgns, "path");
    Wline2.setAttribute("d", "M" + pointx2 + " " + pointy2 + "L" + "500 500")

    Wline2.setAttribute("stroke", "white")
    Wline2.setAttribute("stroke-width", 0.1)
    Wline2.setAttribute("class", "whiteline")

    var Wline1 = document.createElementNS(svgns, "path");
    Wline1.setAttribute("d", "M" + pointx1 + " " + pointy1 + "L" + "500 500")

    Wline1.setAttribute("stroke", "white")
    Wline1.setAttribute("class", "whiteline")
    Wline1.setAttribute("stroke-width", 0.1)

    line.setAttribute("d", "M" + pointx1 + "," + pointy1 + " " + "S" + "400" + " " + "400 " + pointx2 + " " + pointy2)
    line.setAttribute("stroke", color)
    line.setAttribute("fill", "none")
    line.setAttribute("stroke-width", 0.6)
    line.setAttribute("class", clsn)
    document.getElementById("lines").appendChild(line);

    document.getElementById("ttt").appendChild(Wline2);
    document.getElementById("ttt").appendChild(Wline1);
}

function tagHover(tagclass, id, color) {
    $(tagclass).hover(function() {
        $(id).css("stroke", color)
        $(id).css("stroke-width", 6)
    }, function() {
        $(id).css("stroke", color);
        $(id).css("stroke-width", 0.6)
    });
}

function logonode() {
    var GRCC = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'text');
    GRCC.setAttribute("x", 500);
    GRCC.setAttribute("y", 500);
    GRCC.setAttribute("x", 500);
    GRCC.setAttribute("text-anchor", "middle");
    GRCC.setAttribute("id", "GRCC");
    GRCC.innerHTML = "GRCC";
    document.getElementById("ttt").appendChild(GRCC);
    $("#GRCC ").hover(function() {
        $(".whiteline").css("stroke-width", 1.5)

    }, function() {
        $(".whiteline").css("stroke-width", 0.1)

    });
}

var GapPointList = [
    [5, 20],
    [30, 30],
    [40, 40],
    [50, 60],
    [110, 120],
    [210, 220],
    [240, 250],
    [285, 310]
];
var Nodlist = [
    //array of data
];

GraphCirclePoint(5, GapPointList, Nodlist);
GraphCircleLine(Nodlist);

logonode();
```

**My HTML:**

```
body style="background-color: 07101e;">
<svg height="700" width="800" viewBox="0 -80 1200 1200" id="ttt" style="display: block;margin: auto ">   
<g id="white_lines"></g>
<g id="lines"></g>
<g id="text"></g>
</svg>
```

i get errors *(Unexpected string concatenation of literals)* in React every time I want to use `setAttribute` using a variable. and also i get (Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild') ) Error

Comment: I'm not sure React is the problem here.  Can you include enough code that we can see where the React is attached to the Dom and how you're trying to integrate this function with a react JSX element?

Comment: my main question is that how can i transfer "set/get attribute" and "append child" method from js to reactjs / jsx